# how to get the OS information from aws image details

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

I'm not able to find any aws api which will give OS name for a particular ec2 AMI. Can any one help to identify any api for this? I was trying this below api in python and checked with aws-cli also.

```
session = boto3.session.Session(
        aws_access_key_id="",
        aws_secret_access_key="",
    )

ec2_client = session.client('ec2', 'us-east-1')
images=ec2_client.describe_images(
    ImageIds=[
        'ami-011b3ccf1bd6db744',    
    ]
    )
```

This doesn't give me proper information about OS. I can see only for windows images `"Platform": "windows"` comes. How can I get the OS related information?

Answer (score 1):

There's no field that stores distribution name per se.  You'll have to use a combination of image description and owner to determine the ami to run.

Amis disappear as they age as well,  so creating your own ami copies or a dynamic lookup process is best.